# Words going out of page scope will Printing Page by C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following code

#### In HomePg.cs

```
public void PrintMethod()
        {

            PrintPg print1 = new PrintPg();
print1.RefrencePro = comboBoxRefrence1.Text;
print1.print();
            MessageBox.Show("Bill Printed Successfully");
}

private void Save_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
PrintMethod();
}
```

#### In PrintPg.cs

```
class PrintPg
    {
PrintDocument pdoc = null;
String Reference;
public string RefrencePro
        {
            set { this.Reference = value; }
            get { return this.Reference; }
        }
public PrintPg(string Reference)
{
 this.Refrence = Refrence;
}
public void print()
        {
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pdoc = new PrintDocument();
            PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 15);
            PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custom", 100, 200);
            //ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
            pd.Document = pdoc;
            pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
            //pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height =320;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 820;

            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 520;

            pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);

            DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PrintPreviewDialog pp = new PrintPreviewDialog();
                pp.Document = pdoc;
                //pp.Dispose();
                result = pp.ShowDialog();

                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pdoc.Print();
                }
            }
        }
        void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 10);
            float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
            int startX = 50;
            int startY = 55;
            int Offset = 40;
graphics.DrawString("Reference:", new Font("Courier New", 14), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
            Offset = Offset + 20;
            graphics.DrawString(this.RefrencePro, new Font("Courier New", 6), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
            Offset = Offset + 20;
}
```

It's Printing Perfectly but when I am printing the words are going out of print Page as shown in image. I am printing in Microsoft One Note. Is their any way by which I can restrict this and make my reference in new line (Make reference address multiline) after the Page scope end?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/957webty(v=vs.110).aspx) first so you can determine the rectangle that is needed to fit all text on multiple lines. You need to adapt your code as follows:

```
        var text = this.RefrencePro;
        int charsFitted;
        int linesFilled;

        var cn6 = new Font("Courier New", 6);

        var stringFormat = new StringFormat { Alignment= StringAlignment.Near };

        var pageSize = printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize;

        // How much size do we need?
        var measuredSize = g.MeasureString(
            text, 
            cn6, 
            new SizeF(pageSize.Width - startX, pageSize.Height),
            stringFormat, 
            out charsFitted, 
            out linesFilled);

        // Draw the string based on how much space
        // there is needed in the rectangle
        graphics.DrawString(
            text, 
            cn6, 
            new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 
            new RectangleF(new PointF(startX, startY +Offset), measuredSize),
            stringFormat);

        // offset based on the earlier measurements
        Offset = Offset + (int) measuredSize.Height;
```

Comment: this is perfect solution for my problem your solution working perfectly. Thank you so much I am trying to figure out the solution from lot's of time but I does not find the solution you help me lot:)